# UpdateProgress Not working when called thru javascript

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

When i click the button in the update panel i get to see the update progress but  when i try to do this through javascript $("#<%=LinkButton1.ClientID %>").click(); updateprogress is not displayed, but update panel is getting refreshed properly. Any Idea why update progress is not working?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdPnl1" UpdateMode="Conditional" >  
    <ContentTemplate>  
      <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click"   Text="click"/>
       <asp:PlaceHolder ID="Place1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
     </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdateProgress ID="updQuoteProgress" runat="server"  AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdPnl1"  DisplayAfter="0">
        <ProgressTemplate>Loading...</ProgressTemplate>    
</asp:UpdateProgress>

    <script type="text/javascript">    
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#<%=Button1.ClientID %>").click();
        })  
    </script>
```

Comment: I tried your code without modification, and "Loading..." IS shown

Comment: Based on the answer by @Yuriy, In your case script could have loaded fast , in my real application page is heavy and lot of javascript is there in it.

Comment: I made it to sleep, so no. In any case, I am no longer using UpdatePanel, too many issues with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because Sys.Application loaded event occurs after a page's DOM fully loaded. When your script executed the client-side objects responsible for showing UpdateProgress on partial postback not yet initialized.
Try this script instead (place it below the ScriptManager control or just at the page's end):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     Sys.Application.add_load(function () { $("#<%= Button1.ClientID %>").click(); });
</script>
```

You also can delay your script execution with script below:

```
$(function () {
     setTimeout('$("#<%= Button1.ClientID %>").click();', 10);
});
```